# how to get multiples values of a table with a foreign key?

Tags: sql, pdo

how to get all students of a teacher , every student has one single teacher and every teacher has many students , I am using this SQL request , it brings only one single student per teacher , could you help

```
   $data = '';
          $sth = Model::connect()->prepare('SELECT a.name ,
          b.nameTeacher 
          FROM table1 b , table2 a
         WHERE a.id_teacher = b.id GROUP BY b.id');
               $sth->execute();
                 $data = $sth->fetchAll();


        return $data;
```

Table 1

> Teacher :
>
> Id
>
> nameTeacher

Table 2

> Students:
>
> Id
>
> name
>
> Id_teacher

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results and a database tag.  Your query *should* be returning an error, because `a.name` is not in the `group by` and not the argument to an aggregation function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `GROUP BY` and learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT a.name, b.nameTeacher 
FROM table1 b JOIN
     table2 a
     ON a.id_teacher = b.id ;
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select a.name,b.nameTeacher from students a ,teacher b
where a.Id_teacher=b.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.nameTeacher, count(a.name) as numberOfStudents
      FROM table1 b , table2 a
     WHERE a.id_teacher = b.id GROUP BY b.id
```

or:

```
 SELECT a.Id, a.name
      FROM table1 b , table2 a
     WHERE a.id_teacher = b.id and (b.id = [input ID] or b.nameTeacher = [input name]
```